# Change folder tooltip on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

If you hover a folder in Windows 7 you are getting something like the image below. Is there a way to change what this tooltip contains?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method that requires no programming is to use Desktop.ini to create an infotip that displays custom information about the folder and controls some aspects of the folder's behavior.

This blog post outlines how to use them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102.aspx

Desktop.ini file behaviors are generally inherited so the behavior can be applied to one or many folders, depending on where you place it.

Comment: nice. Can this include actual data? Filesize, no of files, last modified or other properties?

Comment: To display dynamic data you would probably need to create and install a shell extension.

Comment: Thanks. Any examples of related projects?

Comment: @Odys, [C++ Windows Shell infotip handler](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppShellExtInfotipHandler-266d4e28). I wouldn't go into this expecting it to be super easy. Explorer shell extensions carry a lot of legacy baggage.

Comment: thank you sir! I mark this answer as correct because of this comment

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create new handlers for folders.

**EDIT FOLDER DETAILS**

Just go to the key
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory" and add, delete, or toggle [properties in InfoTip](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/properties/props). To view them, as stated above, see this [tip](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1194667-how-do-you-add-a-year-to-folder-details/). To edit them, use [Desktop.INI Editor](https://www.howto-connect.com/use-desktop-ini-editor-tool-change-folder-attributes-windows/). Unfortunately, there is a limitation in this program. If you want to directly open it from the folder context menu and edit the desktop.ini properties, you will have to insert the following entries in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DesktopINI Editor]
@="DesktopINI Editor"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DesktopINI Editor\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\DeskEdit\\DeskEdit.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DesktopINI Editor\command]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\DeskEdit\\DeskEdit.exe,0"
```

**ADD THE DETAILS TAB TO THE FOLDER PROPERTIES**

1º - Add the property handler with

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\{883373C3-BF89-11D1-BE35-080036B11A03}]
@="Summary Properties Page"
```

2º - Insert categories in details tab with

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory]
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.DateCreated;System.FileCount;System.TotalFileSize;System.PropGroup.General;System.Comment;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Author;System.Keywords"
```

3º - Insert categories in details pane with

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory]
"PreviewDetails"="prop:System.Comment;System.DateModified;*System.SharedWith;*System.StorageProviderState;*System.OfflineAvailability;*System.OfflineStatus;System.DateCreated;System.Title;System.Subject;System.Author;System.Keywords"
```

**Obs 1:** You can now view the details of the folders via infotip or properties in the context menu and edit them via the details pane (accessible by Alt+Shift+P) of the folder.

**Obs 2:** Make a backup of the key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory
 or create a restore point in case something goes wrong.

Comment: If we depend on Microsoft's usability professionals, we will still need to do this hack 14 years from now. I added something I'd forgotten about: the details tab for folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use the the windows registry editor (Start > Run > regedit) and navigate to

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ *`

It contains a value named InfoTip.  Modify it to add or remove variable entries.  For example, I added System.ItemNameDisplay to the top of the default list:

`prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemTypeText;System.Size;System.DateModified`

refer also to
http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/10/customize-windows-explorer-tooltips/