# Change Details in Tooltip For Specific Folder

Tags: tooltip

Is it possible to change the folder details shown in the tooltip for one specific folder in Windows Explorer?  I want to make it so that when I hover over a specific folder, I only see its creation date in the tooltip.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://superuser.com/questions/402172/change-folder-tooltip-on-windows-7

Comment: Yes, I have.  What about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change folder tooltip on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/402172/change-folder-tooltip-on-windows-7)

Comment: Have you tried the solutions presented in it? If not is there a reason you have not?

Comment: @music2myear After reading it again, I realized that the shell handler allows for the customization of the tooltips of individual files.  I am, however, still unsure as to whether or not it works for individual **folders**.  I also don't know how I would implement it if it did work for folders.  I'm not very familiar with writing shell extensions.  Does it work for folders?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. The question and answers are specifically about folder tooltips. However, I suppose the key piece of information is that the InfoTip field is displayed after the default information, which means the things you're wishing to NOT show are probably default. Regarding writing a shell extension, I have no experience with this either. Our developer sister sites StackExchange or StackOverflow may be a good place to ask questions about that.